# Primeng table - column sort with special character

Tags: sorting, numbers, character, primeng

I have a primeng table my column values are as follows which are displayed as string. They contain a special character(√); Some values contain special character and some wont'
I want to sort them as numbers so that it sorts properly by excluding the special character(√). Is there any way to implement custom sort.

√22.76
√-1.11
√-4.40
4.77
-2.0
√-11.23
√4.5
√6.7

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sortFunction` and the property `customSort`.

You need to set `sortFunction` with the function that will handle your custom logic (and handle the specific character)

You need to set `customSort` to `true`. If you don't, the default sort would be used.

## Template example

```html
<p-table [value]="products3" (sortFunction)="customSort($event)" [customSort]="true">
<!-- ... -->
</p-table>
```

## Typescript part example

```js
customSort(event: SortEvent) {
        event.data.sort((data1, data2) => {
            let value1 = data1[event.field];
            let value2 = data2[event.field];
            let result = null;

            if (value1 == null && value2 != null)
                result = -1;
            else if (value1 != null && value2 == null)
                result = 1;
            else if (value1 == null && value2 == null)
                result = 0;
            else if (typeof value1 === 'string' && typeof value2 === 'string')
                result = value1.localeCompare(value2);
            else
                result = (value1 < value2) ? -1 : (value1 > value2) ? 1 : 0;

            return (event.order * result);
        });
    }
```

In your typescript part, you can handle your symbol to compare as you wish.

[Source documentation of the sort and custom sort](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/sort)

Comment: above logic works great, but It ignores columns  which are empty or with only √. How can we just add those rows to the end of the table